# Additional minifications for Immutable.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, immutable.js

I noticed that Immutable.js is the single largest item in my minified webpack-generated bundle. I quite like it, but would love to find a way to minify it further.

[image]

Comment: Library recommendation requests are off-topic for StackOverflow. Having said that, I'm aware of but haven't used [Immu](https://github.com/scottcorgan/immu), which bills itself as "tiny", so maybe that's what you're looking for? The Immu page also has links to a number of other similar libraries that you may find suitable (it doesn't give a size comparison).

Comment: Minified it is 55Kb. And ~16kb gzipped. Is it a problem?

Comment: I was reading stats.json incorrectly: Immutable.js is the largest *single file* in my minified bundle, but other libraries (like material-ui) are quite a bit larger. The stats screenshot above shows the unminified weight.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable

Here's a blog post talking about some of the problems with ImmutableJS: https://medium.com/@AlexFaunt/immutablejs-worth-the-price-66391b8742d4#.ylfmvj8ug